# Keras Lambda Layer giving ValueError: None values not supported when trying to fit model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I've written a lambda layer in Keras to sparsify an input:

```
def sparsify(x, percent_zero_dims):
    k_val = int((1.0 - percent_zero_dims / 100.0) * K.int_shape(x)[1])

    values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(x, k=k_val, sorted=False)
    # We need to create full indices like [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
    my_range = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, K.shape(indices)[0]), 1)  # will be [[0], [1]]
    my_range_repeated = tf.tile(my_range, [1, k_val])  # will be [[0, 0], [1, 1]]

    # change shapes to [N, k, 1] and [N, k, 1], to concatenate into [N, k, 2]
    full_indices = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(my_range_repeated, 2), tf.expand_dims(indices, 2)], 2)
    full_indices = tf.reshape(full_indices, [-1, 2])
    output = tf.sparse_to_dense(full_indices, K.shape(x), tf.reshape(values, [-1]), default_value=0.,
                            validate_indices=False)
    return output
```

I'm calling the lambda layer in my model by:

```
sparse = Lambda(lambda x: sparsify(x, sparse_perc))(relu)
```

The input shape is (None, 32) and (None, 32) is getting output. I've also written this lambda layer as a custom layer, which throws the same error. If I set the model output to relu, it trains fine, but when I use sparse as my output, the model throws

```
line 360, in make_tensor_proto
raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
```

I can predict on the model, compile, without issues and get the expected results, but when I try fitting it, the model throws an error. I believe it's related to invalid loss getting generated from this output as seen in the stack trace:

```
line 1014, in _make_train_function
self.total_loss)...
```

I've tried removing any nans from the output of the sparse layer (which I know isn't good practice but I'm just tyring to figure out where/how it's breaking):

```
Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.is_nan(x), tf.zeros_like(x), x))(sparse)
```

This happens to me on a couple of other custom layers in the model, but not all of them, which is why I'm confused.

specs:
python 3.5

mac osx

Keras 2.0.4

tf 1.1.0